# Tela de login - não consigo logar um usuario,admin ou user

Tags: java, mysql

tabela usuários;

```
create table usuario(
usuario_nome varchar(15) not null,
usuario_senha varchar(15) not null,
primary key (usuario_nome)
);
```

tabela permissão;

```
create table permissao(
usuario_nome varchar(15) not null,
usuario_permissao varchar(15) not null,
primary key (usuario_nome, usuario_permissao),
foreign key (usuario_nome) references usuario(usuario_nome)
);
```

Inserts;

```
insert into usuario values('matheus','maithe');
insert into usuario values('maithe','matheus');
insert into permissao values('matheus','administrador');
insert into permissao values('maithe','usuario');
```

bean

```
@ManagedBean
public class UsuarioBean {

    private String usuario_nome;
    private String usuario_senha;

    public String login() {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

        try {
            request.login(this.usuario_nome, this.usuario_senha);
            return "dados?.redrect-true";
        } catch (ServletException ex) {

            return null;
        }


    }

    /**
     * @return the usuario_nome
     */
    public String getUsuario_nome() {
        return usuario_nome;
    }

    /**
     * @param usuario_nome the usuario_nome to set
     */
    public void setUsuario_nome(String usuario_nome) {
        this.usuario_nome = usuario_nome;
    }

    /**
     * @return the usuario_senha
     */
    public String getUsuario_senha() {
        return usuario_senha;
    }

    /**
     * @param usuario_senha the usuario_senha to set
     */
    public void setUsuario_senha(String usuario_senha) {
        this.usuario_senha = usuario_senha;
    }


}
```

web.xml

```
<login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/TelaDeLogin.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/TelaDeLogin.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>usuario</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>administrador</role-name>
    </security-role>



    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Tela Usuario</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/telausuario_1.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>usuario</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Administrador</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/dados.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>administrador</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

context.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/ProjetoGrandeRecife" >
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
           driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dp"
           connectionName="root" connectionPassword="root"
           userTable="usuario" userNameCol="usuario_nome" userCredCol="usuario_senha"
           userRoleTable="permissao" roleNameCol="usuario_permissao"/>
</Context>
```

tela de login

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
        <title>Teste</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {background-color: #eeeeee; font-size: 12px}
        </style> 
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <div align="center">
            <p:layout style="min-width:1020px;max-width:1070px;min-height:640px">  
                <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100">  
                    <h:graphicImage library="imagens" name="logo.png" width="1060" height="85"/>
                </p:layoutUnit>
                <p:layoutUnit position="center" size="800" rendered="true">  
                   <br/>
                   <br/>
                   <br/>
                   <br/>
                   <br/>
                   <br/>
                   <div id="msg1" style="background-color: #eeeeee; font-size: 30px">
                    GRANDE RECIFE CONSORCIO DE TRANSPORTE
                </div><br/>
                <div id="msg2">
                    Identifique-se por favor para utilizar
                    o sistema.
                </div><br/>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">

                    <h:outputLabel value="Nome:" for="nome" style="background-color: navajowhite"/>
                    <h:inputText id="nome" style="background-color: #dddddd" label="Nome" value="#{usuarioBean.usuario_nome}"  required="true" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="Senha:" for="senha" style="background-color: navajowhite"/>
                    <h:inputSecret id="senha" style="background-color: #dddddd" label="Senha" value="#{usuarioBean.usuario_senha}" required="true" />
                </h:panelGrid><br/> 
                <h:commandButton action="#{usuarioBean.login()}" value="Entrar" style="position: relative;left: 78px;"/><br/>

             </p:layoutUnit>
            </p:layout>  
        </div>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

Resultado

---

> Message from lcosta,       Thursday, 13:34 28-Jul-2016 13:39:09.356
>   INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-32]
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start The start() method was
>   called on component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ProjetoGrande‌​Recife]]
>   after start() had already been called. The second call will be
>   ignored.

Comment: Não é um erro. É apenas uma INFO.

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho certeza se é isso mas,

Não use underline (_) em nomes de variáveis, você sempre começa com letra minúscula e qualquer outro nome que apareça depois você começa com letra maiúscula. Exemplo: nomeUsuario

De modo que isso talvez gere confusão com os nomes dos métodos `getUsuario_nome()` se tornaria `usuarioNome`, `getUsuarioNome()` e `setUsuarioNome()`.  Faça estes ajustes e veja se o problema persiste.

**EDIT:**

Complementando a resposta, a mensagem que você está recebendo não é um ERROR mas sim um INFO.

> This exception at shutdown happens only if examples webapp was correct
>   when Tomcat started, but was broken afterwards. If it was already
>   broken at startup time, nothing happens.
>
> https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51610 -maybe it
>   help.

Esta exceção só acontece se o webapp estava correto no startup do Tomcat mas foi corrompido depois. Se ele estivesse corrompido já de início nada aconteceria.

Cheque o [link](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51610)

Comment: Gente desculpa o final da mensagem desconsiderem,acabei dando um Ctrl c sem querer, aqui em outro documento.

Comment: O resultado é esse.

Comment: 28-Jul-2016 13:39:09.356 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-32] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ProjetoGrandeRecife]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.

Comment: Favor adicionar isto na pergunta.

Comment: Gente alterei as variáveis mais ainda sem sucesso,alguma dica diferente.

Comment: Tudo bem mais como posso resolver isso,alguém pode me dar uma luz...

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada e vi que a mensagem que você está recebendo é um INFO e não um ERROR.

Comment: Sim mais o que posso fazer para resolver isso,eu vi vários tutoriais e estou fazendo de acordo com que estude,mais possa ser que tenha alguma coisa que eu não consigo achar.

Comment: Qual a versão do Tomcat que você está usando?

Comment: Versão 8 do tomcat

Comment: Notei agora que falta a tag `<form></form>` na sua tela de login. Não?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43155/discussion-between-gleiston-jose-de-santana-and-julian).

Comment: Não consigo acessar o chat de onde estou infelizmente..